# Disco Dingo 19.04 background error

Tags: desktop-background, 19.04

When I started my computer (this is the second boot after installing) my background and login screen background has turned from the Disco dingo background to very bright white with random squares of pixel colors in random orders. In the background switcher(wallpaper if you want to call it that) it still shows it as set to the Disco Dingo background. Any ideas on what may have caused this? I have a more than capable computer, and have the OS installed on an SSD.

Edit: Changing the background to a different, pre-installed one works perfectly, switching back to the default disco dingo switches back to the corrupt colors.

Comment: Does changing the desktop background to anything else work ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Yes, anything except the default works. If I change to the default after changing it will still mess up, it seems to be just that specific one

Comment: So it is possible the image file is corrupt or jas odd permissions set on it. You could either replace the file manually or redownload wallpapers package from the default repositories. I am using phone right now so cannot provide exact package name but  you can do:  apt-cache search wallpaper

Comment: @Wolfgamer478 please add the last part as an ANSWER and accept it

Answer (score 11):

I have an temporarily fix for this problem, Luckly it's very very easy.

press: *alt + f2* ,to open a command screen 
type: *r*
press: *enter*

that's all, the backgrounds have reloaded. its not a fix but it helps till this problem is patched

source: https://www.fosslinux.com/3495/how-to-refresh-desktop-in-ubuntu-without-rebooting-pc.htm

btw some laptops requite to press *alt + fn + f2*

Comment: I get this exact issue every time my laptop wakes from sleep (after upgrading to 19.04). Nice temporary fix!